# Possible to schedule a task to the second with schtasks?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have a file that creates a scheduled task using schtasks:

```
<?php
$cur_dt = new DateTime('now');
$cur_dt->add(new DateInterval('PT60S'));
$cmd = 'schtasks /create /sc once /ru uname /rp pwd /tn "repost_labor" /tr "' . $fname . '" /st ' . $cur_dt->format('H:i:s') . ' /sd ' . $cur_dt->format('Y/m/d');

exec($cmd, $out, $retval);
?>
```

so it generates something that looks like this:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /ru uname /rp pwd /tn "repost_labor" /tr "myfile.bat" /st 12:52:12 /sd 2013/07/23
```

However, even though it is trying to set the seconds, Task Scheduler ignores it and only adds the hour & minute. So if the current time is 12:51:12, instead of the above creating a task at 12:52:12, it creates it at 12:52:00.

Why does Task Scheduler ignore the seconds?

Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: It ignores the seconds, because the /st switch only takes "HH:MM" inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this yet, but I think it would be possible to schedule to the second by creating an xml task file and then using:

```
schtasks /create /xml <filename>
```

because you can include seconds in the xml.